# PowerShell script to delete user profiles, Need help adding to script

Tags: powershell, automation, scripting, active-directory, powershell-4.0

I have created a poSH script to delete user profiles, and retain certain profiles from being deleted. what I need help with is adding a few functions to the script. first I need to add lastusetime to the script so that I can specify users that haven't logged in after a certain amount of days will be deleted. second I need to log all of the users that have been deleted, the logging will need to be stored in a centralized location, maybe using windows event viewer? Lastly I need to make sure we aren't deleting profiles under 30 days since last login, unless the team member is terminated and not on LOA. I will attach the code below.

```
$profiles = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_UserProfile 
#Add whatever users that need to be excluded from the deletion process
$users = 'schaudhary','test2'
foreach ($profile in $profiles){
    if ($profile.Special -ne 'True'){
        if ($profile.LocalPath.split('\')[-1] -notin $users) {
            $profile | Where-Object { $_.LocalPath.split('\')[-1] } | Remove-CimInstance -WhatIf
            Write-Host "deleting" $profile.LocalPath
        }
    }
}
```